# soapui- testrunner.sh - takes only one .xml file as input?

Tags: soapui

I am running soapui tests using command line. Right now it looks like this:

/bin/testrunner.sh -j -a -f"output"  -R"Project_Report" -F"HTML" /path_to_xml_file/sample.xml

I want this to run all .xml files under /path_to_xml_file/. Something like

/bin/testrunner.sh -j -a -f"output"  -R"Project_Report" -F"HTML" /path_to_xml_file/*.xml

But its not working. I do not want to group all tests into one .xml file.

I tried using a for loop like this:
for file in `ls *.xml`; do 
  /bin/testrunner.sh -j -a -f"output"  -R"Project_Report" -F"HTML" /path_to_xml_file/$file
done

But there is another problem. Only the last .xml file's test result is seen in the .html file. It is overwriting all the previous test results.

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks!

Comment: Is there a -f flag on linux?  I use windows, and there is a flag:  -f    (Sets the output folder to export results to).  If you have that you could use the a directory name which has the filename in it (or a timestamp) to separate the html files

Comment: @chrismead: Hi, my example shows the -f option (-f"output"). Under this folder soapui creates folders with the .xml file name and puts all the .html files under it. But each file name is different and its difficult to generalize code to pick all the folders and the .html file under it

Answer (score 1):

Doh!  I didn't see your -f flag the first time.

I am not sure that I have much more to offer, but to even share this at all I need to add it in as an answer (so it is readable).

Here is a batch file that I use to run the testRunner batch file.  I know that you aren't using Windows, but I'd guess that at least some of this stuff is cleaner and easier on linux.  Basically the idea is to:

- clean up from the last run
- create a timestamp named directory for the results
- run the test
- dump the run output to a file
- grep (findstr) the output looking for errors
- copy all the output to the timestamp named folder

If you did something along these lines in linux you should be able to make sure all your HTML files are captured.  If you need to then gather all the HTML files into a list, I'd guess that you could grep again to get that list.

Sorry that I don't have a Linux example.

```
@ECHO OFF
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
set hour=%time:~0,2%
if "%hour:~0,1%"==" " set hour=0%time:~1,1%
set timeClean=%hour%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%
set mydate=%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%
set timestamp=%mydate%_%timeClean%
set newDir=TestResults\%timestamp%
set projFileName=%1
set testSuite=%2
set baseDir=%3
echo BASE DIRECTORY = %baseDir%
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
del /F /S /Q %baseDir%soapui*.log
del /F /S /Q %baseDir%global-groovy*.log
del /F /S /Q %baseDir%soapui*.log.*
set file=%baseDir%\%projFileName%
set newFolder=%baseDir%Results_%timestamp%
echo %newFolder%
mkdir %newFolder%
set newSummaryFile=%newFolder%\testSummary.txt
echo Executing test %projFileName%
call testrunner.bat -s%testSuite% -r -j -I -S -f%newFolder% %projFileName% >    %newFolder%\summary.txt 2>&1
@ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 -w 1000 > nul
set "content=Failed tests (if any) line numbers:"
for /f "tokens=1,8*" %%i in ('findstr /I /N /C:"ASSERTION FAILED" /C:" ERROR"  %newFolder%\summary.txt') do call :addLines Line %%i %%j
goto :end
:addLines
for /f "tokens=1 delims=::" %%z in ("%2") do set "linenum=%%z"
set "content=%content% %1 %linenum%"
GOTO :eof
:end
echo %content% > %newSummaryFile%
xcopy /F *.log %newFolder%
```